# TauriJS writeBinaryFile cannot freeze array buffer views with elements

Tags: arraybuffer, jszip, uint8array, tauri

I work with [TauriJS](https://tauri.studio/v1/api/js/modules/fs#writebinaryfile) and try to modify a zip file with [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and later save it with writeBinaryFile.

```
function saveFile(org_path, new_path, pack_format) {
    var zip = new JSZip();

    // get file
    var org_file = await window.__TAURI__.fs.readBinaryFile(org_path);
    await zip.loadAsync(org_file);

    // edit file
    var pack_json = await zip.file("pack.json").async("string");
    pack_json = JSON.parse(pack_json);
    pack_json.pack.pack_format = pack_format;
    zip.file("pack.json", JSON.stringify(pack_json));

    // save file
    var array_zip = await zip.generateAsync({type:"uint8array"});
    await window.__TAURI__.fs.writeBinaryFile(new_path, array_zip);
}
```

This is the code I currently have. The problem is that it gives the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot freeze array buffer views with elements

I wasn't able to find a solution to this error, is it somehow possible to bring the zip file in the right format to save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix the problem on this page:
https://qdmana.com/2022/144/202205241127535226.html

This is my adjusted code:

```
function saveFile(org_path, new_path, pack_format) {
    var zip = new JSZip();

    // get file
    var org_file = await window.__TAURI__.fs.readBinaryFile(org_path);
    await zip.loadAsync(org_file);

    // edit file
    var pack_json = await zip.file("pack.json").async("string");
    pack_json = JSON.parse(pack_json);
    pack_json.pack.pack_format = pack_format;
    zip.file("pack.json", JSON.stringify(pack_json));

    // save file
    zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then((content) => {
        var file = new FileReader();
        file.readAsArrayBuffer(content);
        file.onload = function (e) {
            var fileU8A = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
            window.__TAURI__.fs.writeBinaryFile({ contents: fileU8A, path: new_path + ".zip" });
        };
    });
}
```